# how to read integer values from serial port in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a Keyence camera which communicates through RS-232. It is configured to output three integer values when triggered. I'm having trouble reading the integer values. I try to use a char array buffer but it only reads the first + sign in the output. I tested it using putty and output is something like this

+346.0,+261.0,098

I want to know if there is anything I need to use to read integer values like these?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        char[] buffer1 = new char[200] ;


        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        port.Open();
        if (port.IsOpen) { Console.WriteLine("port is now open"); } else { Console.WriteLine("port not opened correctly"); }

        port.Write("T"); //triggers the camera

        port.Read(buffer1, 0, 200);

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(buffer1[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You might have to read it as a string and parse it yourself, splitting on the commas

Comment: Always best to show the code you are using that doesn't work. Much easier for people to tell you where you went wrong then...

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm new to stackoverflow and thanks for reminding me. I have added the code i was using.

Comment: Do you know more about the protocol for communicating with the device?  Does it specify anything to denote it is done writing?

Comment: No, I just have to send commands as strings like R for run, T for trigger, etc.

Comment: You cannot ignore the return value of Read(), it will not be 200.  It takes time to receive the response.  Consider using ReadLine() instead if the string is sent with a terminator like line-feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the port.ReadTo("\r") and it works, as the output ends with a carriage return.

But I want to know what is the advantage of using a data received event?

Comment: I would set the newline property on SerialPort to "\r", and then you can call port.ReadLine to perform the same function.  By setting the newline property it will also change how the lines are written when you use WriteLine, it will end the line with whatever value is set in NewLine.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues before with reading from the serial port and not reading in everything expected.

Turns out I was reading in the response from the device and it wasn't done yet writing.  I figured the serial port object would continue trying to fill the buffer until the read timeout was hit, and that was not what was happening.

In my scenario I knew how many characters I was going to be reading from the serial port.  So if you know that you could implement a repeat on the read until your character buffer is full.  I don't know if the same would apply if you are reading from SerialPort.BaseStream.

```
SerialPort serialPort; 

char[] buffer = new char[expectedLength];
int totalBytesRead = 0;

//continue to read until all of the expected characters have been read
while (totalBytesRead < expectedLength)
{
    totalBytesRead += serialPort.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, expectedLength - totalBytesRead); 
}
```

Comment: I tried putting in your code but it did not wrok, should I put in a delay to let it finish writing all the values and then try to read?

Comment: @ranjith1512 I would not add a delay, setting the ReadTimeout on the serial port would be a better option.  If you are still reading just the "+" from the port with my code than I doubt adding a delay or setting the ReadTimeout would work, especially since the default ReadTimeout value is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use (simplified):

```
public class Scanner : SerialPort
{
    private string _word;
    private int _globalCounter;
    private readonly char[] _rxArray = new char[2047];

    public Scanner()
    {
        DataReceived += MyDataReceivedEventHandler;
    }

    public event EventHandler<CodeScannedEventArgs> CodeScanned;
    private void MyDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
            var rxByte = (byte)ReadByte();

            // end of word
            if (rxByte == 10)
            {
                // first byte (02) and last two bytes (13 and 10) are ignored
                _word = new string(_rxArray, 1, _globalCounter - 2);

                DisplayData(_word);

                _globalCounter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _rxArray[_globalCounter] = (char)rxByte;
                _globalCounter++;
            }
        } while (BytesToRead > 0);
    }

    private void DisplayData(string receivedText)
    {
        OnCodeScanned(new CodeScannedEventArgs(receivedText));
    }

    protected void OnCodeScanned(CodeScannedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<CodeScannedEventArgs> handler = CodeScanned;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The scanner I use adds byte 02 as a prefix and bytes 13 and 10 as postfix to everything it scans, so it is pretty easy for me to break it up into words. You'll obviously need to change the implementation slightly so it works for you.

Edit - CodeScannedEventArgs class:

```
public class CodeScannedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CodeScannedEventArgs(string scannedCode)
    {
        ScannedCode = scannedCode;
    }

    public string ScannedCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using this code in windows forms? Can it be used in a console application?

Comment: I am using it in Windows Forms, but it doesn't matter really, you can use it in console application also.

Comment: Which namespace should I add to use CodeScannedEventArgs?